# Dygraphs - Create a Chart with "draggable" points

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Was wondering if there is a way in the dygraphs to enable draggable points in the sense that when a graph has been  generated the user can drag (down or up) a specific point in the graph and the graph will adjust accordingly ?

Is there a way to emulate such a  behaviour in Dygraphs ? Haven't found any information about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but there's no out-of-the-box support for it. You'd have to write your own [interaction model](http://dygraphs.com/tests/interaction.html) to catch the initial `mousedown` event and subsequent `mousemove` and `mouseup` events. You'd probably implement this by changing the underlying chart data during the drag.

Note that click+drag already has a meaning in dygraphs: it zooms the chart.